# Create DLL without building project

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have two applications

- Parent application.
- Child application.

**WORKING STRUCTURE**

- The code of child application is compiled from the parent application.
- I have added a `DLL` named  `MyDLL.dll` in the parent application(There is a feature in parent application to upload DLL and compile code of child application from there). The child application also consumes that `DLL`.
- Now I need to create a `DLL` of child application. Since `MyDLL.dll` is in parent application I cannot build the project of child application individually(since child application also consumes that `MyDLL.dll`).

When I build the child application, its showing the error : `Could not Find namespace MyDll. Are you missing an assembly reference?`

**CODE**

**1. Parent Application**

```
using MyDll;
namesapace MyNamespace
{
   class ParentApplication
   {

   }
}
```

**2. Child Application**

```
using MyDll;
namesapace ChildNamespace
{
   class ChildApplication
   {

   }
}
```

How do I generate a `DLL` of child application without building project of child application?

Comment: "How do I generate a DLL of child application without building the child application" no...just, no

Comment: Sorry. Its **building project of child application** instead of **building the child application**. @David Pilkington

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build the child application because until the code is compiled into a dll then well, its just code on a screen. Since, C# is compiled into Microsoft Intermediate Language [MISL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht8ecch6(v=vs.90).aspx) which is then compiled against the common language run time (CLR) and then that is made to native code like machine code. Where you can read more about [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht8ecch6(v=vs.90).aspx).
So in short, you have to build the child application, no other way around it.

It also seems like you aren't using the right location for the `MyDll.dll`, where exactly is it located?

Comment: Yes. I know. In normal time it should be compiled to get dll. I can't add `MyDll.dll` to the Child application because its already added in Parent application. @James Loyd

Comment: The Child application is working perfectly when the child's solution with classes exist in Parent application directory. Now I need to convert child application  to DLL and add it to the Parent application directory instead of placing solution with classes. @James Loyd

Comment: Yes you are right. Dll cannot be generated without building the project. I found the solution. The parent application has a feature to build DLL for the child and the issue is solved. Thank you for your answer and precious time :) @James Loyd